# Multiline Matching

Tags: regex, svn, replace, notepad++

I have some old repository patch/diff files, and I want to use a regex to remove everything but the added lines.

Given that the added lines in the diff *never* start with a `'+'`, I tried to use [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)'s "Replace" dialog with "Regular Expression" and ". matches newline" selected and:

**"Find what":** `(\+|.*?\n\+)([^+].*?)(\n|$)`
**"Replace with":** `+\2\n`

I believe [this is correct](https://regex101.com/r/e6LVOh/1), but in Notepad++ It will only match the 2<sup>nd</sup> line in a row that begins with a `'+'`. So for example Notepad++'s replacement of this:

```
         float   minBlur;
         float   maxBlur;
-        double   minSpeed;
-        double   maxSpeed;
+        float   minSpeed;
+        float   maxSpeed;
+        float   medianSpeed;
```

Looks like this:

```
+        float   maxSpeed;
+        float   medianSpeed;
```

But I believe it should look like this:

```
+        float   minSpeed;
+        float   maxSpeed;
+        float   medianSpeed;
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is here? Or if perhaps there is a workaround?

Comment: I have just tried in NPP, and got 3 lines with `+` at the start. So, you are trying to remove any line not starting with `+`? Try `^(?!\+).*\R*` with an empty string as a replacement (but with *`.` matches newline* option disabled)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What version do you have? I'm running with the Sep 21 2016 build.

Comment: I have NPP v.7.2.1, Nov 20 2016. I believe your regex is not actually correct if you need to do what I think you want to do (see my above comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you need to remove any line not starting with a plus.

You can use the following solution that should work consistently in the recent NPP versions:

*Search*: `^(?!\+).*\R*` 
*Replace*: `<empty>`

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of a line
- `(?!\+)` - there must be no `+` at the line start
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (as the *`.` matches newline* option should be DISABLED)
- `\R*` - 0+ line break sequences.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this also picks up the filename lines beginning with "+++" in the files. I'm  going to see if I can extend your regex a bit to solve the problem, but this is definitely a better way to approach the problem.

Comment: `^(\+\+|[^+]).*\R*` works like a charm. Thanks I didn't know about the `\R`.